# How can I force all facets in a ggplot2 plot to have the same x:y scale ratio, but allow the scales themselves to vary?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with plotting data where the slope of x-y relationships between groups is what I want my readers to compare. The groups of data have very different ranges, though, so if i make a line plot and facet the plot by groups, a lot of white space on some of the plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,6,9), y=c(1,2,3,2,4,6,3,6,9), group=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'))

ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y))+
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  geom_line()
```

So this plot lets you see that facets A and C have the same slopes, but there's a lot of white space in facet A, which I want to eliminate. (The problem is even worse in my real data... The line in A basically compresses down to a point)

[image]

But of course, if I let the scales vary freely, all the lines appear to have the same slope.

```
ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y))+
  facet_wrap(~group, scales='free')+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

How can I make it so that each plot's scale has the same unit RATIO of x:y, preserving the visual slope comparison, while allowing the scales to vary so that at least one axis in each facet is fully "used"? (The axis that is fully "used" will of course vary depending on the data.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to make separate plots for each group and then lay them out together. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(patchwork)

data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,6,9), y=c(1,2,3,2,4,6,3,6,9), group=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'))

pl = data %>% 
  group_split(group) %>% 
  map(
    ~ggplot(.x, aes(x=x, y=y))+
      facet_grid(. ~ group) +
      geom_line()
  )

# Get ratio of axis ranges
ar = pl %>% map_dbl(function(p) {
  yr = layer_scales(p)$y$get_limits()
  xr = layer_scales(p)$x$get_limits()
  diff(xr)/diff(yr)
})

# Remove redundant axis labels
pl[2:3] = map(pl[2:3], ~.x + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()))
pl[c(1,3)] = map(pl[c(1,3)], ~.x + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()))

wrap_plots(pl, nrow=1, widths=ar)
```

[image]

Note that this approach will not work well if the range of aspect ratios is quite large. In that case, another option is, for example, to have equal-width plots and vary the y-range of each plot to result in the correct relative slopes across plots.

Comment: That was my first thought too but isn't it visually the same as OPs second plot? I was thinking of something like `wrap_plots( by(data, data$group, function(i) { ggplot(data=i, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + coord_equal() }) )`

Comment: Sorry. I obviously didn't read the question as carefully as I should have. See updated answer.

Comment: Would not simply setting x limits separately for each plot do the job as well?